# Unable to add react native plugin

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to add react-native firebase plugin.
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase
Unfortunately i am stuck at this issue. Any help will be appreciated

[check link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vp6Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update your app/build.gradle on Android Studio

com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm

```js
dependencies {
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    ...
    
    // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
>>> compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    // Firebase dependencies
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.6.0"
}
```